# How to absolute position an element with percentages?

Tags: css, css-position, absolute

I have an element that I'm trying to absolute position to the center and right near the bottom. Whether I do 50% from right or left, seems to be slightly off center.

In this screenshot you can see that it's a little to the left from center.

[image]

```
a.down {
    font-size:70px;
    color:#fff;
    text-align: center;
    bottom:5%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 50%;
}
<a href="#we-are-the-leader" class="down">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: try margin:auto it should fix your problem and start creating jsfiddle

Comment: margin:auto does not go w/ absolute positioning does it? I need to have it absolute positioned 5% from the bottom at all times...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are willing to use CSS transforms, the solution is extremely straight forward:

```
a.down {
    font-size:70px;
    color:#fff;
    text-align: center;
    bottom:5%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 50%;
    transform: translateX(50%);
}
```

As transformation percentages are computed based on the dimensions of the element, using a positive 50% translation along the x-axis simply repositions the element to the right, of half of its computed width—achieving the perfect horizontal alignment.

If you're using `left: 50%`, use a negative value for the translation instead.

Comment: that didn't work but transform: translateX(50%); did so +1 and accepted answer. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here are four possible ways that I can think of...

1. Use `calc()` on left position. *You need to know element's width...*
2. Use `translateX()` on left position and add negative percentage. *No need to know element's width.*
3. Use simple `margin-left` if left position and set it to negative half of element's width. *You need to know element's width...*
4. Set `left` & `right` to 0 and use `margin: auto`. *No need to know element's width...*

**Examples** (all elements are one above another, because of same positions)

[CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/dvLden/pen/eNvMVR)

```
a.down {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5%;
  font-size: 70px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.down:before {
  content: "\f107";
}

a.down-1 {
  left: calc(50% - 22.5px);
}

a.down-2 {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

a.down-3 {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -22.5px;
}

a.down-4 {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you position absolutely like that you will position the *edge* of your element relative to the `right` side. You must adjust for the width of your element using a margin, e.g.:

```
margin-right: -35px;
```

However, this does require you to know the width of your item.

Demo:

```css
a.down {
    font-size:70px;
    text-align: center;
    bottom:5%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 50%;
}

/* Added for demo: */
.fa-angle-down:before { 
  content: '■';
}

a.down {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 70px;
    margin-right: -35px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#we-are-the-leader" class="down">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: Or you can simply use negative CSS translation, which doesn't require you to know the width of the element—`transform: translateX(-50%)` should work.

Answer (score 1):

This solution will center any content you place in the wrapper.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="my-class">
    <a href="#we-are-the-leader" class="down">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.my-class {
    font-size:70px;
    text-align: center;
    bottom:5%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**Notice:** Width is set to 100%.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the absolute position tricks as follows.

```css
body {
    background: navy;
}
a.down {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 5%;
    margin: auto;
    display: table;
    font-size: 70px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<a href="#we-are-the-leader" class="down">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my guess :
Try wrapping your 'a' tag into a div "flexed into 1" and margined 0 vertically and some % horizontally (try to find your best % to center the div !) just like this :

```
.center{flex : 1;
margin:0 30%;}
```

with your **HTML** inside this :

```
<div class="center"></div>
```

Try it out.

https://jsfiddle.net/LsgL07en/46/